# If the jar file of a J2ME MIDlet gets copied from one phone to another, do its records get copied too?

Tags: java-me, jar, copy, records, rms

Apologies if this question has been asked before. After lots of searching, I could not find the answer anywhere.

I was just reading about something called a Record Management System for J2ME. This can be used so a MIDlet can store data reasonably permanently, even after it has been closed or the phone has been turned off. However, what I don't know is where these records actually get stored. Consequently, I find some things about records confusing.

To give an example, let's say I have a game of some sort on my phone. This game is a J2ME MIDlet and it stores my highest score in a record, so that way each time I play the game, it'll display what my highest score was. If I were then to copy the jar file for this game from my phone to another phone, would the record storing the high score also get copied to the other phone, or would no record exist yet on the other phone?

Also, another question about records while I'm at it. If I uninstall a MIDlet that stores records from my phone, do the records get deleted automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you are sending your application to one mobile to other then only application will be
send not its Records

Records are connected with its midlet so if you are installing that application on other phone
you will get blank record store

if you are uninstalling your midlet from mobile it will automatically remove all the record store in it.
so next time when you start application you will found none of your previous record.